# [Spartacus ]Posting from Iframe to OCC endpoint configuration issue

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am integrating 3ds for spartacus. The payment provider requires a POST back from an iframe they serve. I post back to an endpoint in OCC. I have added the origin to the allow-from `corsfilter.commercewebservices.allowedOrigins=http\://localhost\:4200 https\://localhost\:4200 https\://test.domain.com`

The XSSFilter is blocking the request because of this configuration `xss.filter.header.X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN`, this property is set in hybris platform. When I remove this property manually, the POST is working properly. When set it to an empty string (`xss.filter.header.X-Frame-Options=`) chrome rejects the requests because of an erroneous header.

How I can I remove this property in configuration, without manually removing the property every time the server restarts?

Comment: Are you on ccv2? Or on custom infrastructure/

Answer (score 0):

I am running locally at the moment, but should run on both ccv2 and on custom infrastructure. Hopefully without changes to the http server (nginx/apache) as this is part of a library that we want to publish for spartacus.